# How to multisig a transaction function?

Tags: solidity, multisignature

I have a smart contract for selling Painting in crowdsale, Once the Painting is sold in crowdsale the owner of the painting can trade it to other user once the crowdsale is over. I have to implement  a buy function where the buyer can buy the painting only if the seller has interest to sell it.The problem I am facing is that How can a buyer  know whether the seller  is  interested and at what cost is he comfortable to sell? Once solution I have thought is that to make the function multisig where both buyer and seller need to sign to transfer the painting and accept the Payment.

**Ps** :- How to implement multisig feature to a function to sign

Comment: How about just a `setPrice` (callable by the seller) and `buy` (callable by the buyer)?

Comment: The Price will already be set  when the token is being  purchased by the first buyer(i.e seller ) . But what if the seller don't have interest to sell the painting. can I have a mapping for the interest  to sell?? And then by using that mapping we can know the seller intent.

Comment: Then they can call `setPrice(2**256-1)`.

Comment: No I cannot set the price as 0 because the painting has to be sold at price greater than the price it was purchased and the platform will get commission on that sell.

Comment: I'll just delete that comment, as it seems to have confused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the painting ownerships are stored in a mapping, you can create, another mapping where the owner set if he wants to sell it or not, for instance:

```
mapping(address => uint256) public paintingOwnership; // this assumes the painting id is a number
mapping(uint256 => bool) public sellStatus;

function buy(uint256 paintingID) public {
    require(sellStatus[paintingID],"Painting is not for sale")
    // do here the required to make the transaction between tokens/ether and the painting
}

function changeSellStatus(bool value) public {
    require(paintingOwnership[msg.sender] > 0);
    uint paintingID = paintingOwnership[msg.sender];
    sellStatus[paintingId] = value;
}

function availability(uint256 paintingID) public pure returns(bool){
    return sellStatus[paintingId];
}
```

The function `buy` will be executed by the buyer and will only be executed if the painting is for sell. Buyers can also check `availablity` with the function provided. The seller will use `changeSellStatus` to set if they want to sell `(True)` or not `(False)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly, I was also thinking of the same. Thanks for clearing the air.